# Conexão Banco de Dados Android Studio passando Date

Tags: php, android, hashmap

Estou tendo problema com o seguinte, eu faço a conexão com o Banco de Dados tudo certo mas no código eu uso um Map de parametros  pois passo userName, password, etc, porém preciso passar uma variavel do tipo Date tbm. Todas essas variaveis vao ser mandadas para um código em php. Como Poderia resolver isso??

Segue o código abaixo:

```
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String birthDate, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener, String email, int gender)
{
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("userName", name);
    params.put("userNick", username);
    params.put("userPassword", password);
    params.put("userBirthDate", birthDate);
    params.put("userEmail", email);
    params.put("userGender", gender + "");
}



@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converte a data em milisegundos (long) e guarda no seu Map. Pode criar 2 métodos utilitários pra fazer essa conversão. Por exemplo:

```
public long DateInMillis(int year, int month, int day, int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

    return c.getTimeInMillis();
}

public CharSequence FormattedDateFromMillis(Context context, long dateInMillis){
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(context, dateInMillis);
}
```